# Tomcat ajp port change every time with intelliJ

Tags: jsp, servlets, intellij-idea, tomcat7, ajp

I am using mod_jk to connect apache to tomcat server in my project. 
I am using intelliJ IDEA as my development IDE.

Problem with me is, Every time I restart my tomcat in intelliJ, it starts ajp listener on different port. I see below lines in intelliJ console.

```
May 17, 2013 2:19:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 17, 2013 2:19:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-1377"]
```

when I restart next time ajp-bio-xxxx shows different port.
Why this happens? I want to set it to fixed port.

Where the tomcat is installed, I checked server.xml file it shows 8009 as ajp port.
Then why intelliJ changes it every time? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I resolved the problem.

IntelliJ was using a different catalina base path, where it was creating different server.xml and other configuration files.

by passing CATALINA_BASE to tomcat when running, I forced it to use same folder which is currently used by tomcat server installed, I got it running. :)